# Page changes back on its own

Tags: javascript

**To reproduce**, click on 1 svg play button, then click the **Exit button**.

Click on a 2nd svg play button and then don't touch anything.

You will notice that the page goes back to the svg play buttons on its own without touching anything.

How is that fixed in the code? https://jsfiddle.net/pw2zLskj/

Issue is viewable in the snippet I provided and in the jsfiddle link.

Page should only change back to the svg play buttons when the Exit button is clicked.

After clicking a 2nd svg play button, the page should not change back to the group of svg play buttons on its own.

That is the only thing I am trying to fix in the code.

```
  function resetPage() {

    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("fadingOut");
    document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("animationend", function() {

      document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("fadingOut");
      resetBackground("body");
      resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
      showAllButtons(".container.hide");
      resetButtons(".outer");
    });
  }
```

```js
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function showBackground(background) {
      background.classList.remove("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(showBackground);
  }

  function resetCurtains(curtainSelector) {
    const allCurtains = document.querySelectorAll(curtainSelector);

    function showCurtain(curtain) {
      curtain.classList.remove("active");
    }
    allCurtains.forEach(showCurtain);
  }

  function showAllButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {

    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("fadingOut");
    document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("animationend", function() {

      document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("fadingOut");
      resetBackground("body");
      resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
      showAllButtons(".container.hide");
      resetButtons(".outer");
    });
  }

  function hideCurtains(exitButtons) {
    const container = exitButtons.closest(".inner-container");
    const curtains = container.querySelector(".sliding-panels");
    curtains.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function exitClickHandler(evt) {
    resetPage();
    hideCurtains(evt.currentTarget);
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function hideBackground(background) {
      background.classList.add("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(hideBackground);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function hideButton(button) {
      button.classList.add("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(hideButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  function markAsPlayed(played) {
    played.classList.add("played");
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    resetPage();
    markAsPlayed(evt.currentTarget);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function createResetHandler(player) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", function resetVideoHandler() {
        player.destroy();
      });
    })
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    createResetHandler(player);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    return player;
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
    playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
    playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
    playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
    playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;

    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 1,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  };
  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
  }

  function createCallback(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    return function callback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function playerAdder(parent, playerOptions) {
    const wrapper = parent.querySelector(".wrap");
    return function callback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    show(wrapper);
    const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    wrapper.player = player;
  }

  return {
    adder: playerAdder,
    createCallback
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const parent = document.querySelector(coverSelector).parentElement;
    const callback = managePlayer.adder(parent, playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, callback);
  }

  addPlayer(".playa", {});
  addPlayer(".playb", {});
  addPlayer(".playc", {});
  addPlayer(".playd", {});
  addPlayer(".playe", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  addPlayer(".playf", {});
  addPlayer(".playg", {});
  addPlayer(".playh", {});
  addPlayer(".playi", {});

  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });

  manageUI.init({});
}
```

```css
.play1 {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play2 {
  --color-a: purple;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: purple;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play3 {
  --color-a: green;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: green;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play4 {
  --color-a: orange;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: orange;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play5 {
  --color-a: yellow;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: yellow;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play6 {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: orange;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play7 {
  --color-a: red;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: green;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play8 {
  --color-a: white;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: white;
  --color-d: black;
}

.play9 {
  --color-a: red;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadingOut:before,
.fadingOut .isOpen {
  animation: fadingOut 1s;
}

@keyframes fadingOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 290px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.outer.isOpen {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

body.bg1 {
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
}

body.bg1 .with-curtain:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.thePlay {

  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.played {
  fill: green;
}



button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  fill: red;
  padding: 0;
}

.exitsvg {
  fill: none;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 17.80202103;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  border: 4.625px solid #4e4e4e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain4 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain4 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain5 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain5 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain6 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain6 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain7 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain7 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain8 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain8 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain9 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain9 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container play1 with-curtain">
    <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g id="play">
          <title>Play</title>
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
          <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path d="M 6.3895625,6.4195626 C 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437" />
            <path d="M 6.3894001,93.6106 C 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play2 with-curtain">
    <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play3 with-curtain">
    <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play4 with-curtain">
    <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain4">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play5 with-curtain">
    <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain5">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play6 with-curtain">
    <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain6">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play7 with-curtain">
    <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain7">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play8 with-curtain">
    <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain8">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play9 with-curtain">
    <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain9">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask you a couple questions about the sample here? I'm not certain what your sequence of events are to perform each action (I'll dig through in a second), but:
1. Are you dead set on this approach?
2. how are you managing state?

Comment: If there is a better way to do it, you can provide an answer, sure.

Comment: Fair enough. Then may I ask: what is the desired effect here? Not programmatically, what's your vision for what it should DO? Like I get there's a grid of play buttons. You click one, it switches to "theater mode" until user clicks exit. Do the buttons always play the same video? Because if I click the same one twice i get different ones

Comment: After clicking a 2nd svg play button, the page should no change back to the group of svg play buttons on its own.

Comment: I understand that. That's the PROBLEM. What's the overall intention? I'm not being pedantic here, I think there's an easier way to fix this, but I wanna make sure I get what you're after

Comment: That is the only issue in the code that I am trying to fix.

Comment: Tip: `document.querySelector("body") === document.body`. Anyway, I see some repeated `addEventListener` on persistent elements with no corresponding `removeEventListener`, so it’s probably something related to that.

Comment: The point I was making is this is a fairly convoluted way to handle the transitions. Here: https://codepen.io/NerdyDeeds/pen/b6a0cba73d2036c929d64c8abfa50ff5 This doesn't even use JS. Straight CSS. Take advantage of the free processes the CSS engine affords. (Obviously you'd change out the content cards and the images. It's an EXAMPLE)

Comment: How would I be able to do that in my code? I would very much prefer to use CSS. Can you provide it in an answer?

Comment: I... did? The link there is a working example. Replace out the "curtain" styles with your images, and the iframes with your players. Done. I even set it up so the backgrounds are all dynamic so you can swap in your patterns.

Comment: Put my code in there then provide it on here as an answer so I would be able to accept it as an answer.

Comment: I see. In that case, I advise you accept @ggirodda's answer, below. Replace your `resetPage` method with the one he's clearly explained after his excellent diagnosis. He got there before me.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is on `document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("animationend", ...`, at line 42. This event is triggered when a css animation ends. The first time is working because the `resetPage` is called only after you click on exit button. So after click on exit button, you add an event listener on animationend, and you always have an animatioon end when curtains closes.

**SOLUTION**

The solution is to remove the event listener on css animationend once the function is executed

```js
function resetPage() {

    document.body.classList.add("fadingOut");
    const onAnimationEnd = function() {

      document.body.classList.remove("fadingOut");
      resetBackground("body");
      resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
      showAllButtons(".container.hide");
      resetButtons(".outer");
      document.body.removeEventListener("animationend", onAnimationEnd)
    }
    document.body.addEventListener("animationend", onAnimationEnd);
  }
```

Comment: How is that fixed in the code?

Comment: I added the `resetPage` function with the correction in the answer

Comment: This answer satisfies the requirements. In particular, the "That is the only thing I am trying to fix in the code." addendum.